# Discord bot with animated emojis

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have a discord bot and I would like to know how I can make the bot use animated emoticons on the server. I have tried other bots that put animated emoticons through WebHooks or put the bot itself to put animated emoticons. But I can't get it to work in any way.
If anyone can help me thanks.
**KKtua**

Comment: I presume you already have a framework in place - your bot starts up, runs basic commands etc. Do include some code samples of what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the bot needs to be in the server where the animated emoji is, so if you want to use an emoji from the 'Rocket League' server, then the bot has to be in that server.

Once you know the bot is in the server which has the emoji, what you need to do is type the emoji in chat yourself with a \ before the emoji, so that you get the emoji ID, which you will need to copy and use in the bot code, example of an animated emoji used in a bot message:

```
message.reply('here is a cool emoji -> <a:check_no:717523612906684428> ');
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that way and it works for me. But if I want to put a normal smiley it doesn't work. How do I put a normal smiley on?

Comment: If you use a backslash behind the emoji it will send another kind of the same emoji in chat and you can simply copy paste it in the code if it's a standard emoji. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you and solved your problem