# Animated Emojis For Bot

Tags: python, discord

I am not sure on how to send animated emojis through discord bots.
Here is my current command to try and send an animated emoji, but it only sends the name itself.

```
patrick = client.get_emoji(895366056221220955)
 if message.content.lower() == "patrick":
        await message.channel.send(f"{patrick}")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot with animated emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813494/discord-bot-with-animated-emojis)

Comment: The tags are discord.js and I'm on python,  but I don't know if that's a mistake.

Comment: Whoops, but if you put `<a:check_no:895366056221220955>` in the message, does it work?

Comment: This does not unfortunately work!